# Passing a message from contentScript to popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I need get the url of a current tab using my Chrome extension and pass that URL to popup.js.

I am sending a message to a contentScript:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {result: "getURL"}, function(response) {
  });
});
```

On message in contentScript i am sending a response:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if((request.message == "getURL")){
            alert("hovno");
            sendResponse({url: window.location.href});
        }
    }
);
```

Then I am listening in popup.js and try to store the message in my url variable:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        // read `newIconPath` from request and read `tab.id` from sender
        if(request.url){
            url = request.result;
            alert("něco");
        }
    });
```

However it seems like the contentScript never gets the message, because the alert is never shown. What am I missing there?

Comment: Sounds like your content script wasn't running which may occur for a variety of reasons depending on how you declare/inject it. However you don't need the content script here at all: simply use `tabs[0].url` inside your query() callback. Also, make sure you know how asynchronous JS works: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: @wOxxOm perfect, I used the chrome.tabs.query and its working as charm. Thanks!